# Getting only error conditions from status callback

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I am using the status callback when calling out and it works well but I would only like to get "error" conditions like **busy**, **failed**, **no-answer**, and **canceled**. I can get those if I simply specify only **completed** as my StatusCallbackEvent but I'd like to not receive the **completed** event as well. What do I pass to only get the errors?

I'm using the Python 6.x helper library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

From [the documentation on making calls and status callbacks](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls#status-callback-event-parameter):

> The **completed** event is fired when the call is completed, regardless of the termination status: **busy**, **canceled**, **completed**, **failed**, or **no-answer**. If no StatusCallbackEvent is specified, completed will be fired by default.

There's no way to not receive the **completed** event when getting the status callback for the end of a call. I recommend that in your application where you receive this callback you check the parameter as early as possible and return early if you don't want to deal with it.